# Using data.table from list

Tags: r, data.table

I put some data frame "ID","DATE" into List.
So now I have two List size of 30

```
[[1]] 
ID date
1  2018-01-01
2  2015-02-01
...
[[30]]
ID date
2  2015-03-05
```

and I had to use code below.

```
library(data.table)
for(i in 1:30){
setDT(A[[i]])[, join_date := date]
setDT(B[[i]])[, join_date := VISIT_DATE]
}
```

The problem was the next code.

```
for(i in 1:30){
append <- B[A, on = .(ID, join_date), roll = "nearest"]
}
```

How can I use lists in this code?

Comment: Why don't you do `rbindlist(A, idcol = TRUE)` and work with that? Then you won't need loops.

Comment: You need `B[[i]][A[[i]], on =...]`, otherwise you're not using the `i` index anywhere.

Comment: expanding on Roland's comment: `dtA <- rbindlist(A, idcol="IDX")[, join_date := date]; dtB <- rbindlist(B, idcol="IDX")[, join_date := VISIT_DATE]; dtB[dtA, on=.(IDX, ID, join_date), roll="nearest"]`